# Clarification: Homotopy of pairs vs relative homotopy in relative homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, homotopy-theory

Let $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ be $CW$-pairs, and let $f,g:(X,A) \longrightarrow (Y,B)$ be maps of pairs. The below definitions follow Arkowitz.

A *relative homotopy* from $f$ to $g$ is defined to be a map
$F:X \times I \longrightarrow Y$ such that $F(-,0) = f, F(-,1) = g$ and $f(A,t) = f(a) = g(a)$ for all $t$.

On the other hand, a *homotopy of pairs* from $f$ to $g$ is defined to be a map $F:X \times I \longrightarrow Y$ such that $F(-,0) = f, F(-,1) = g$ and $F(A,t) \subseteq B$ for all $t$.

Both of the above define an equivalence relation the set of maps of pairs $\{f:(X,A) \longrightarrow (Y,B) \}$. This set, quotiented by either equivalence relation, could be referred to as the set of (relative) homotopy classes of maps $(X,A) \longrightarrow (Y,B)$.

When defining *relative homotopy groups* (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$) Arkowitz gives the following. For a $CW$-pair $(X,A)$, define $\pi_n(X,A) = \pi_{n-1}(X_A)$, where $X_A$ denotes the homotopy fibre of the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$. It is then shown that $\pi_{n-1}(X_A)$ can be regarded as *homotopy classes of maps* $(D^n,S^{n-1}) \longrightarrow (X,A)$.

My question is, when we refer to *homotopy classes of maps* in the last sentence of the above paragraph, which equivalence relation are we using? Relative homotopy, or homotopy of pairs? It would seem as though the "correct" equivalence relation is homotopy of pairs (and this is what Arkowitz seems to show), but that seems to be confusing terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I just happened to be working through that section when I noticed your question. By my reading, "homotopy of pairs" is intended, not "relative homotopy".

Arkowitz refers the reader to Hilton's "Introduction to Homotopy Theory" (p. 17-19) for further details regarding Remark $4.5.4$ on relative homotopy groups (Hilton was Arkowitz's advisor, and I've noticed that Arkowitz often follows Hilton). In the cited reference, the equivalence relation used appears to be what you are calling "homotopy of pairs". In both Hilton and Arkowitz, it seems that whenever the more restrictive form of homotopy is intended, the "rel $A$" notation is used explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer (too long for a comment): I'm curios about the "right answer" in order to understand how to think properly to these groups too. However, in Arkowitz there is a Lemma, I believe $4.5.5$, which seems to explain in his statement how one should think about being null-homotopic in relative groups, in particular which equivalence relation to use, as you asked for.

Infact, when you think to relative groups it seems that the "right" should be relative homotopy (according to Lemma) since it states: $[f] = 0$ if and only if exists a map $g: (E^n,S^{n-1}) \longmapsto (Y,B)$ with $g_{|_{S^{n-1}}} = f_{|_{S^{n-1}}}$ and $f \simeq g$ relative to $S^{n-1}$, which is the definition of relative homotopy you gave.

Comment: Yes, I see. However, consider homotopy groups $\pi_{n-1}(Y_B)$ of the homotopy fibre of $B \hookrightarrow Y$, where we model $Y_B$ as paths that start in $B$ and end at $*_Y$. Elements are classes $[f]$ where $f:S^{n-1} \rightarrow Y_B$, and the adjoint is a map of pairs $\hat{f}:(CS^{n},S^{n-1}) \rightarrow (Y,B)$. If $g \in [f]$, then the adjoint is a map $\hat{g}:(CS^n,S^{n-1}) \rightarrow (Y,B)$ which surely does not necessarily have to agree with $\hat{f}$ on $S^{n-1}$, unless I misunderstand something? Because $g$ being homotopic to $f$ does not mean that $f(x)(0) = g(x)(0)$.

Comment: @Matt I agree with you, I'm going to reflect about it.